# Will wild horses jump wooden fences?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Trivia) it says:

> It is possible to jump over wooden fences while riding a horse.

However, will a wild horse also jump over a fence ([1.5 blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence))?  If so, what can I use instead to contain them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they won't. That jump can only be controlled by you once the horse is tamed by pressing the space button while riding it. But if you want to be 100% sure a horse won't leave any place you can still use a [lead](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lead) and tie the horse to a fence.

Comment: Actually, the leads seem to be bugged and despawn in certain conditions. The fences are fault-proof though, and additionally the horse is more than 1 block wide, so 1-wide gaps, doors, single fence gates and the likes are too narrow for horses to escape.

Comment: I'm more interested in keeping a horse in a fenced area.  I'd prefer to not use leads as it's somewhat of a zoo on a server so free-roam is preferred.

Comment: @SF., once fixed leads won't despawn. But yeah, they are buggy right now.

Comment: @Batophobia, then fences are ok.